# Resize video capture to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I've looked at a number of similar questions, and tried implementing those solutions, but I'm still having the same problem, I believe primarily because I have an additional complication (and the fact that my understanding of image manipulation is limited).

Here's the situation: in a web app I have a webcam picture capture (using `getUserMedia`).  The `<video>` element which displays the feed, as well as the `<canvas>` are sized to 640 pixel width as default.  This works fine on desktop browsers.

On devices with screen width under 700px, the site responsively resizes everything, including the picture capture dialog, which resizes to 95% of the screen width, thus the `<video>` element display the camera feed is less than 640px in width most of the time (those are the times that matter here).  The video feed displays fine, you can see the entire camera field.  But every you take a picture, it gets displayed on the canvas (which resizes the same as the video feed) clipped, depending on the size of the screen.  That is to say, the canvas displays as much of the original image, which remains 640px wide, as it can.

I don't want to resize the actual image; I'd like the uploaded data at the end of the day to be a 640px image regardless of the screen width.  I just want the user to be able to see the whole thing before s/he saves it.

I've already tried playing with `width` attribute (element attribute, not CSS) on the canvas, but that did nothing, and changing the `width` of the video display will shrink the actual image, so that's not what I want.

I also played with the `drawImage` method which should resizing, but I couldn't quite get what I wanted.  This is the line I thought should work, but still gives me a clipped image:

```
if($(window).width()<701){
var ratio = videoHeight/videoWidth;
  var canvasWidth = $(window).width()*.86; // calculated width after CSS resizing
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0,width,height,0,0,canvasWidth,canvasWidth*ratio);
}
```

## Update

The following code will show the entire picture on the canvas, but shrinks it, and I get a much smaller image file, depending on the screen width it was taken on:

```
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0,canvasWidth,canvasWidth*ratio);
```

Many thanks!

Comment: you should have a look to `video.videoHeight` and `video.videoWidth` which will respectively give you the actual height and width of the video stream (640px)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although I'm not necessarily committed to improving this particular feature any more.

Comment: I was looking for an other similar question when I found yours unanswered, only saw the last active date after that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I proportionally resize a video in canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778559/how-do-i-proportionally-resize-a-video-in-canvas)

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the suggestion.  At the moment it's not urgent for me to solve this, since shortly after asking it I found a partial solution that is good enough for now, as I noted in the edit to the question.  I don't know when I'll get around to checking out the solution in the similar question.

Comment: ok, then add it as a self-anwser, you will be able to accept it in few days

Comment: @Kaiido I would, but it doesn't actual solve the original problem.