# How do I proportionally resize a video in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm having trouble proportionally scaling the video frame when rendering a video element on canvas.

## What I've tried:

I read the selected answer to [How to proportionally resize an image in canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087483/how-to-proportionally-resize-an-image-in-canvas) but it did not work for me. I'm rendering an HTML5 video frame rather than an image. This might seem unusual, so here it is explained: [video + canvas = magic](http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/)

My problem with adapting the answer to that related question might have been:

- Maybe the video size works differently than an image.
- maybe I incorrectly converted the answer used for that specific situation to mine, since it uses confusing static measurements ('300') in multiple places, without really explaining them.

## What I have so far

Right now, my player works, fitting the video to it, but it stretches to fit.

```
context.drawImage(videoPlayer, 0, 0, canvasPlayer.width, canvasPlayer.height); 
//canvasPlayer -> HTML5 canvas, videoPlayer -> HTML5 video element
```

I'd like to know (respectively):

- how to fill the height vertically, remaining proportional.
- how to fill the width horizontally, remaining proportional.

**How can I do this?**

Comment: I don't have much experience with `canvas` but I know for doing fluid video elements, there was a hack I had to essentially do with padding because CSS isn't aware of how to maintain aspect ratio. [This](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) was the article I referenced for a lot of that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to get the video drawn proportionally into the canvas (keeping the aspectRatio):

```
// var c = canvasElement, v=videoElement;
// fill vertically  
var vRatio = (c.height / v.videoHeight) * v.videoWidth;
ctx.drawImage(v, 0,0, vRatio, c.height);

// fill horizontally  
var hRatio = (c.width / v.videoWidth) * v.videoHeight;
ctx.drawImage(v, 0,0, c.width, hRatio);
```

```js
function draw(){

  // fill vertically
  var vratio = (c.height / v.videoHeight) * v.videoWidth;
  ctx.drawImage(v, 0,0, vratio, c.height);
  
  // fill horizontally  
  var hratio = (c.width / v.videoWidth) * v.videoHeight;
  ctx1.drawImage(v, 0,0, c1.width, hratio);  
  
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}


var c=document.createElement('canvas');
c.width = 640;
c.height= 480;
var ctx = c.getContext('2d')

var c1 = c.cloneNode(true);
var ctx1 = c1.getContext('2d')

var v = document.createElement('video');
v.controls=true;

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('fill vertical\n'));
document.body.appendChild(c);
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('fill horizontal\n'));
document.body.appendChild(c1);
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('original'));
document.body.appendChild(v);

var anim;
v.onplaying = function(){
 anim = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  };
v.onpause= function(){
 cancelAnimationFrame(anim);
  };
 
v.onloadedmetadata = function(){v.play();};
v.src = 'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4';
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
inputs[0].addEventListener('change', inpHandler);
inputs[1].addEventListener('change', inpHandler);
function inpHandler(){
 c[this.name]=this.value;
 c1[this.name]=this.value;
 v.currentTime=0;
 v.play();
}
```

```css
canvas{border:solid 1px;}
canvas,video{ display:block;}
```

```html
<label for="width">width</label>
<input name="width" type="number" value="640"/>
<label for="height">height</label>
<input name="height" type="number" value="480"/></br>
```

Comment: You use ternary operator to calculate `vRatio` or `hRatio` but both expressions after the condition are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I make a example for you, check it out!

code pen : http://codepen.io/cstony0917/pen/BNvxZP?editors=101

```
var v = document.getElementById("video1");
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var i;

var video_width = v.offsetWidth;
var video_height = v.offsetHeight;

var ratio = video_width / video_height;

var target_width; 
var target_height;
var y_of_video = 0;
var x_of_video = 0

if ( video_width > video_height ){
  target_width = c.width;
  target_height = c.width / ratio;  
  y_of_video = (c.height - target_height) / 2 ;
}else{
  target_width = c.height;
  target_height = c.height * ratio;

  x_of_video = (c.width - target_width) / 2 ;
}


v.addEventListener("play", function() {
  i = window.setInterval(function() {
    ctx.drawImage(v, x_of_video, y_of_video, target_width, target_height);
  },20);
}, false);

v.addEventListener("pause", function() {window.clearInterval(i);}, false);
v.addEventListener("ended", function() {clearInterval(i);}, false);
```

Comment: I think that this is not quite correct - you proportionally changes the size of the canvas, but not the size of the image that you paint on canvas which has already been given.

Comment: OK , I make some change of this example , It maybe more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little fix in [@Tony Hsieh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681105/tony-hsieh) solution

```js
if ( video_width > video_height ){
  target_width = c.width;
  target_height = c.width / ratio;  
  y_of_video = (c.height - target_height) / 2 ;
} else{
  target_width = c.height * ratio;
  target_height = c.height;

  x_of_video = (c.width - target_width) / 2 ;
}
```